# Planned maintenance scheduled for Oct 30 & 31, 2021, starting at 13:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

Update 2021-10-31T14:19:00Z: We are done. Thank you for your patience and all your supportive tweets.

Update 2021-10-31T13:22:00Z: Today's work will be starting shortly.  https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1454800691898339329 and https://stackstatus.net/post/666565626004979712/maintenance-beginning

Update 2021-10-30T17:07:00Z: The site is back.  It took a lot longer than expected (our apologies) but we decided to take the safe/slow route rather than take some risks.   Tomorrow's maintenance window is still required.

Update 2021-10-30T14:00:00Z: This will be starting soon. Once the website go into read-only mode it will last 1-2 hours.   See https://twitter.com/StackStatus until we are back.

Due to ongoing planned network upgrades, all public Stack Exchange properties (stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, and so on) will be in read-only mode during two maintenance windows: Saturday, October 30 and Sunday, October 31, 2021.

While in read-only mode, the public Q&A network sites will be accessible, but no new content may be added or modified (questions, answers, comments, votes, etc.). Also, Teams will not be accessible as it requires authentication that is paused in read-only mode.

Once read-only mode starts, it is expected to last no more than 2 hours, though our goal is much shorter.

Before and after the window, updates will be added to this post.  During the window, updates will be posted to https://twitter.com/StackStatus and https://stackstatus.net

##### Schedule:

- Window 1 – Sat, 2021-10-30. Start: [13:00 UTC / 9AM ET](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=30&hour=13&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240). End: [15:00 UTC / 11AM ET](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=30&hour=15&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240).
- Window 2 – Sun, 2021-10-31. Start: [13:00 UTC / 9AM ET](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=31&hour=13&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240). End: [16:00 UTC / noon ET](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2021&month=10&day=31&hour=16&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=179&p4=136&p5=240).

##### What is happening?

This is the last of 4 major network hardware upgrades planned for 2021.  While all of our network equipment is redundant and can usually be upgraded without downtime, there are a few rare procedures that are high risk *or* require us to switch to read-only mode to avoid actual downtime.

While these upgrades involve many days of actual work, we have minimized the user-visible interruption and isolated it outside of peak usage times.

Expect a blog post with the exciting details after we've had time to recover. This has been quite exhausting.

Comment: Will consecutive visit days be recorded during maintenance? (if not, I'll lose my 202 day streak)

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE The site's only going to be down for two hours - I could understand your question if it were 8 or 12 or more but two hours out of a 24 hour window seems like a tiny one to be concerned about.

Comment: I fully expect a Halloween-themed maintenance page.

Comment: SE being down is spooky enough @OrangeDog :D

Comment: @OrangeDog LOL.

Comment: I saw a maintainance screen today for a few seconds, is that related?

Comment: @dan1st Not related.  Must have been a fluke.  The yellow banner that says we're in read-only mode is automatically generated and sometimes gets fooled.

Comment: @dan1st maybe it was just to spook you... for Halloween :P

Comment: Completely unsurprisingly but quite annoyingly, the advice to check the StackStatus account on Twitter was useless because it had again not published any information about this "planned" outage (though apparently it was updated a while after the site was set to read-only). Do you really need your users to advise you on the usefulness of starting a practice to write down a list of things which you botched several times in the recent past?

Comment: @tripleee Information was published on the StackStatus Twitter.

Comment: I checked repeatedly during I think the first 15 minutes of the outage; nothing.

Comment: @tripleee Updates were delayed, but they were posted. Perhaps you would like to rephrase your comment a bit.

Comment: Re v8: is it the forty-fifth day of October already?

Comment: "While all of our network equipment is redundant" doesn't sound too good (redundant: not or no longer needed or useful). How about "While all of our network equipment has resilience"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - "Redundant" is fairly commonly used to mean "duplicate components for reasons of fault-tollerance".  It was the nearly-universal term before "resilience" became popular.  See, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(engineering)

Comment: This was poorly executed.  Was supposed to be done by 11am EST, lasted over that past +2 hours.  Also what is up with the constant downtime during the weekends?  What are you guys doing that is causing this ?

Comment: @BenScott I should have suggested "has redundancy." In the context of upgrading, "redundant" can easily be read to mean that the equipment is out-of-date. Not all SE sites are related to computer technology.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's an interesting point about the use of the word "redundant".  I'll take that into consideration next time.  Thanks!

Comment: @Catija Maintenance that's expected to be quick and easy has a habit of becoming the most convoluted and complicated problems. 

https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1454496008684068865

Comment: @TomLimoncelli Dual redundant, multiply-redundant, and so on, wouldn't have startled me, and I expect that form would keep the people who might favour the use of redundant happy.

Comment: Should this still be featured now that the maintenance period is over?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica no, it shouldn't.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug: the post for the second maintenance beginning didn't have the question link (only in text) while the first one had a link. Also,it hasn't been updated....

Comment: @VScode_fanboy "Also,it hasn't been updated" I'm unsure which you are referring to.  Link?

Comment: @TomLimoncelli https://www.stackstatus.net/, it says will be starting shortly, LOL.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy If you click on the link it says "And… we’re done! All systems are back to normal. Thank you for your patience." but I now see that if you just look at the blog that isn't clear. 
 Thanks for pointing that out! 
 https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/666565626004979712/maintenance-beginning

Comment: @TomLimoncelli Welcome..

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow search was broken for the duration of the outage, returning a 500 internal server error. Is this a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? All other network sites' search pages were fine.

[image: Screenshot of web browser displaying Stack Overflow Search page: "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"]

Comment: I noticed this as well.

Comment: Friend of mine SMS'd this on, he used the latest Chrome.